# Reactjs:Scroll issue in newest google chrome android? migrated Earlier version: 99.xxxxxx.... Newest version: 116.xxxxxx

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, google-chrome

Earlier my website was working fine, And it was full screen. And later on I updated the chrome(Android) to the latest(116.xxxxxx....). Now it is showing scrolling which was not used to be in earlier version(99.xxxxxx...).

Tried most of the CSS solutions like below.

```
html, body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}

AND

html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer,

It was caused by the newest resize behaviour of google chrome(Android).

Solution is to add:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

in your index.html file.

You have to prepare your application for the newest resize behaviour in Chrome(Android) if you have used

> position:fixed

in your web layout.

reference: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/